# Bang! replacement parts

Tags: bang

I recently got Bang The Bullet special edition. Unfortunately I did not realise that this edition does not have the bullets that represent life for each character and I really like that specific mechanic. Other than using some other kind of thing to represent the life. Does anyone know of a place that I can get some spare parts?)

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the manufacturer and see what they have to offer but since that item did not come with your game you are probably out of luck. You can just use the back of another character card and track your life with the bullets that are printed on it. Considering it would be a very small market to make replacement parts like that I would highly doubt that you will find anyone that makes them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for bullets to represent life, look into purchasing snap caps or plastic dummy rounds. These products are normally used for safe handgun dry fire training.

If there is a gun show near you, you can likely get a pack of 20 for 15 dollars. Or try [e-commerce.](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_condition-type_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3375251%2Ck%3Asafety%20training%20ammo%2Cp_n_condition-type%3A6503254011&keywords=safety%20training%20ammo&ie=UTF8&qid=1452997638&rnid=6503252011)

Answer (score 0):

The back of the character cards have bullets printed on them for this purpose. Take some unused character cards and tuck them under the used ones so players can track their health.